# Is it possible to virtualize 32-bit environment on Hyper V (x64)?

Tags: hyper-v

I'm planning a test environment in several platforms include both 32/64 bits but I'm not sure about the hardware 32 bit could be virtualize through HyperV or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUre it can. Hyper-V simulates a 64 bit environment. You can install a 32 bit operating system on a 64 bit processor, or? ;) I did not see any 32 bit normal processor (outside some low poewer stuff) in the last years.